# Modular game engine: DLL circular dependencies

Tags: c++, dll, module, directx, game-engine

I want to create a game engine as a training & portfolio project and the modular approach sounds promising but I have some problems with the module design.

First I want to create low level modules like Rendering, Application, Utility etc. and use them in high level modules like Terrain.
So the dependency would kinda look like this Game<-Engine<-Terrain<-Rendering.

I want to create multiple Rendering "sub modules" like Rendering.Direct3D11 and Rendering.OpenGL. That's where I would have circular dependencies. The sub modules would use interfaces of Rendering and Rendering would need to manage the sub modules, right?
Game<-Engine<-Terrain<-Rendering<-->Rendering.Direct3D11

I could probably create a module like RenderingInterfaces and break the circular dependency but that seems like a hacky workaround. I was planning to use the "sub module design" multiple times like for:
Game<-Engine<-Application<-->Application.Windows

Is the sub module design ugly? Is there a way to use the sub module design without circular dependencies?

Comment: You might want to look at Alistair Cockburn's [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) page.  When I read your description, it sounds exactly like what you are trying to do.

Comment: @legalize I will look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this abstractly. Let's say you have three dylibs: `Game.dll`, `Renderer.dll`, `SubRenderer.dll`.

The renderer interface might look like this (simplified):

```
// Renderer.h
class SubRenderer
{
public:
     virtual ~SubRenderer() {}
     virtual void render() = 0;
};

class API Renderer
{
public:
     explicit Renderer(SubRenderer* sub_renderer);
     void render();

private:
     SubRenderer* sub_renderer;
};
```

You can stick that in `Renderer.h` or something like that, and the Renderer constructor and `render` method can be implemented in `Renderer.cpp` which you include for the project that outputs `Renderer.dll`.

Now in `SubRenderer.dll`, you might have a function like this:

```
// SubRenderer.h
class SubRenderer;
API SubRenderer* create_opengl_renderer();
```

That can be implemented in `SubRenderer.cpp` which is compiled/linked to output `SubRenderer.dll. It might look like this:

```
// SubRenderer.cpp
#include "SubRenderer.h"
#include <Renderer.h>

class OpenGlRenderer: public SubRenderer
{
public:
    virtual void render() override {...}
};

SubRenderer* create_opengl_renderer()
{
    return new OpenGlRenderer;
}
```

Last but not least, in some source file in Game.dll, you can do something like this inside some `Game.cpp`:

```
// Game.cpp
#include <Renderer.h>
#include <SubRenderer.h>

int main()
{
    SubRenderer* opengl_renderer = create_opengl_renderer();
    Renderer renderer(opengl_renderer);
    renderer.render(); // render a frame
    ...
    delete opengl_renderer;
}
```

... of course hopefully with a safer design that conforms to RAII.

With this kind of system, you have these header dependencies:

```
`Game.cpp->Renderer.h`
`Game.cpp->SubRenderer.h`
`SubRenderer.cpp->Renderer.h`
```

In terms of module dependencies:

```
`Game.dll->Renderer.dll`
`Game.dll->SubRenderer.dll`
```

And that's it -- no circular dependencies anywhere. `Game.dll` depends on `Renderer.dll` and `SubRenderer.dll`, but `Renderer.dll` and `SubRenderer.dll` are completely independent of each other.

This works because this `Renderer` can use a `SubRenderer` given its virtual interface without knowing exactly what it is (thus requiring no dependencies to the concrete type of 'sub-renderer').

You can put `Renderer.h` somewhere that is centrally accessible from all three projects with a common include path (ex: inside an `SDK` directory). There is no need to duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this the bridge or adapter pattern?

Comment: Probably bridge since the focus is more on decoupling the representation than polymorphism -- but it also has those adapter-like qualities as well from renderer to sub-renderer.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need for a reverse dependency in your design.

This is all about interfaces. Your rendering module need a native rendering API (sub-module, in your terms), but it shouldn't care if it is OpenGL or Direct3D11. The API sub-modules just have to expose a common API ; something like `CreatePrimitiveFromResource()`, `RenderPrimitive()`... These sub-modules shouldn't be aware of the upper layer, they just expose their common API.

In other words, the only "dependencies" needed is that the rendering module depends on a rendering sub-module (using the common interface), and the rendering sub-modules don't depend on anything (in your engine), they just expose a common interface.

---

Simple example :

We have a rendering module "IntRenderer" that renders integers. Its job is to convert integers to characters and print them. Now we want to have sub-modules "IntRenderer.Console" and "IntRenderer.Window", to print in a console or in a window.

With that, we define our interface : the sub-module must be a DLL that exports a function `void print( const char * );`.
This whole description is our interface ; it describes a common public face that all our int renderers sub-modules must have. Programmatically, you could say that the interface is just the function definition, but that's just a matter of terminology.

Now each sub-module can implement the interface :

```
// IntRenderer.Console
DLLEXPORT void print( const char *str ) {
    printf(str);
}

// IntRenderer.Window
DLLEXPORT void print( const char *str ) {
    AddTextToMyWindow(str);
}
```

With that, the int renderer can just use import a sub-module, and use `printf(myFormattedInt);`, regardless of the sub-module.

You can obviously define your interface as you want, with C++ polymorphism if you want.
Example : sub-modules X must be a DLL that exports a function `CreateRenderer()` that returns a class that inherit the class `Renderer`, and implements all its virtual functions.

Comment: I didn't work a lot with interfaces so I'm a bit confused. My idea was putting the interfaces into the rendering module and using them in the sub-modules but you're suggesting to put the interfaces into the sub-modules, right? With multiple sub-modules I would need to share the interfaces so I would need to create a module just for the interfaces or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Vider7CC Just to clarify, an interface is just a generic concept. The idea is to have a common public "face" that can be used regardless of the implementation. What your interface is, is up to you. Now, if I understood correctly, you have a rendering module that do some rendering jobs. Something like, the rendering module have terrain data and must render it ? In this case, the job is done by the rendering module, so the rendering module is the one to use the submodules, so the interface is on the submodule side.

Comment: @Vider7CC In other words, if you have some interchangeable boxes, you have to define an interface to be able to use any box, regardless of the flavor. The interface is here to hide the different flavors, and is part of each box (each box implements the interface).

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. I guess I understand what you mean but my problem is probably the implementation of this concept. I thought the c++ interfaces would be a solution for that but I guess they cause the circular dependency.

Comment: @Vider7CC Added examples to explain.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the awesome help. I understand the concept but the implementation with c++ inherit-interfaces would still cause a circular dependency. Let's say I have the base class(c++ interface) in the Renderer module and I want to implement the methods in the sub-modules. The sub-modules would have a dependency to the Renderer module because they need to know about the base class to inherit from it.

Comment: @Vider7CC In this case, the base class is part of the interface, so it is the part that is shared between the interface users and implementers. It is defined in a `.h` that is the same for all everyone. There should be no code in it, just declarations. The module then use the `.h` to use the interface (and the sub-modules). This is normal, the module needs to know about the interface to use it, and the sub-modules need to know about the interface to implement it, regardless of how you define your interface.

Comment: Yeah that's kinda what I thought. So you are suggesting to create a copy of the .h  in each module to solve the circular dependency instead of sharing one single header? I'm sorry for asking so much here in the comments.

Comment: @Vider7CC It depends on how you do it, and how you want it. If you compile the module and sub-modules separately, you will probably prefer a copy everywhere. If you choose the sub-module at compile time, you can probably share the file.

Comment: I would love to share the file but that's my original problem. Putting the header in Rendering and using it in the sub modules would create a dependency to Rendering. I will search for ways to share the header but I'm probably forced to copy them in each module. Thanks for your help and time.